# Why is the 2nd homotopy group of the circle trivial?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

As stated in the title I am trying to prove  $\pi_{2} (S^1) \cong 0$ . I have no clue where to start. I know that the meaning is: there is no way to transform a sphere into a circle.

Can anyone help me on elaborating the proof? I would be so glad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f: (S^2, x_0) \to (S^1, y_0)$ be a continuous map. Our goal is to show that $f$ is homotopic to the trivial map sending every point in $S^2$ to $y_0$.

Recall that $\mathbb R$ is the universal cover for $S^1$. Let $p : (\mathbb R ,z_0) \to (S^1, y_0)$ be the standard projection map. Since $\pi_1(S^2, x_0) = 0$, it is clear that $f_\star(\pi_1(S^2, x_0)) \subset p_\star (\pi_1(\mathbb R, z_0))$. Therefore, by the lifting criterion, our map $f : (S^2, x_0) \to (S^1, y_0)$ lifts to a map $\widetilde f : (S^2, x_0) \to (\mathbb R, z_0)$ obeying $p \circ \widetilde f = f$.

But $\mathbb R$ is convex, so $\widetilde f$ is clearly homotopic to a trivial map sending every point in $S^2$ to $z_0$. Composing this homotopy with $p$, we see that $f$ is homotopic to the trivial map sending every point in $S^2$ to $y_0$, as required.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. 

I am trying to understand what you wrote. I do not understand the terms "universal cover", standard projection","lifting criterion" "lifts to a map","convex" :(

But I do understand the overall idea that you explain in the first sentence :)

Comment: No worries! The map $p : \mathbb R \to S^1$ is defined by $p(x) = (\cos x, \sin x)$. So you can visualise the $\mathbb R$ as a "winding staircase" above the $S^1$.

Comment: The main idea is to show that given any map $f : S^2 \to S^1$, you can "lift it upstairs", i.e. you can find a map $\widetilde f : S^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $p \circ \widetilde f = f$. The reason this is helpful is that it is clear that $\pi_2(\mathbb R) = 0$. Hence there is a homotopy $\widetilde F$ from $\widetilde f$ to the trivial map from $S^2 \to \mathbb R$. Therefore, $p \circ \widetilde F$ is a homotopy from $f$ to the trivial map from $S^2 \to S^1$.

Comment: To show that this "lift" $\widetilde f: S^2 \to \mathbb R$ exists, we use the lifting criterion (page 61 of Hatcher), which amounts to checking that $f_\star(\pi_1(S^2)) \subset p_\star (\pi_1(\mathbb R))$.

Comment: Okay, now I get what p does :) and the second part you wrote as well about the f and f˜ but I do not understand why $\pi_2(\mathbb R) = 0$

Comment: Ah, that's the bit about $\mathbb R$ being convex. Let me phrase it like this: If $X$ is any space, and $f: X \to \mathbb R$ and $g: X \to \mathbb R$ are any two maps, then $f$ is homotopic to $g$. The homotopy is $F: X \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ sending $(x,s) \mapsto sf(x) + (1-s)g(x)$. The conclusion is that any map from $S^2 \to \mathbb R$ is homotopic to the trivial map.

Comment: Ah I see :D that's amazing. 
I found the book and the lifting criterion :) But what is $f_\star$ i.e. what does the star do/mean?

Comment: When you have a continuous map $f : X \to Y$, you automatically get a group homomorphism $f_\star : \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)$. To define this map $f_\star$, recall that every element of $\pi_1(X)$ is itself a map $\sigma : S^1 \to X$. But then, $f \circ \sigma$ is a map $S^1 \to Y$. So we define $f_\star : \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)$ by sending each $\sigma $ to $f \circ \sigma$.

Comment: Thank you so so much. I think I might get it now. I'm going to sleep over it and try to put it on paper tomorrow. :) will let you know if it worked.

Comment: No worries. Good luck!

Comment: Note that this works for all $\pi_n$ with  $n>1$.

Comment: @KennyWong does this argument also work to prove that $\pi_q(S^1) \cong 0$ for any $q>1$? Can I use the same argument to prove that $\pi_q(S^n) \cong \pi_q(\Bbb R P^n)$ for $n,q>1$?